# Different time for getting value from two arrays different length

Tags: c#

I was surprised that getting value by index from the first array need more time then from second one. It is not depend on arrays lenght, in my tests it is true for any combinations. I guess that it is depends on some low level optimizations. Can somebody explain it? 
code example is bellow:

```cs
            var a1 = new int[10];
            var a2 = new int[1000000];

            #region init
            var random = new Random(12345);

            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
                a1[i] = random.Next(1000000000);

            for (int i = 0; i < a2.Length; i++)
                a2[i] = random.Next(1000000000);

            #endregion

            Console.WriteLine("a1 Length = " + a1.Length);
            var watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var t1 = a1[a1.Length / 2];

            watcher.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("a1 timestamp = " + watcher.ElapsedTicks); // average value 130-150 ticks


            Console.WriteLine("a2 Length = " + a2.Length);
            watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            var t2 = a2[a2.Length / 2];
            watcher.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("a2 timestamp = " + watcher.ElapsedTicks); //average value 10 - 15 ticks


            Console.ReadLine();
```

My result is:
- getting value by the index from array with lenght 10 is ~130-150 ticks
- getting value by the index from array with lenght 1000000 is ~10-15 ticks

Comment: That's not how you do performance / execution time measurements. Not at all. Execute each of your measured code pieces many thousand (millions, perhaps) times, measure the total execution time of these thousands/millions invocations and then calculate an average execution time for a single invocation. Or just use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) for peace of mind.

Comment: Hey @elgonzo, thanks a lot for your suggestion. I have used BenchmarkDotNet and it shows new aspects. Looks like Pavel's assumption is right. Only first call to the any array needs a lot of time. Next one is a realy faster...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to change how you measuring the performance, but let's assume that your measurement is correct. It could be a few reasons here and one of them is branch prediction. In short, modern processors are using branch prediction for their computations.

As it says [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor):

> The purpose of the branch predictor is to improve the flow in the
>   instruction pipeline. Branch predictors play a critical role in
>   achieving high effective performance in many modern pipelined
>   microprocessor architectures such as x86.

So the digital circuit is trying to identify a pattern and follow it. If you guess right every time, the execution will never have to stop and it goes fast and if you guess wrong too often, you spend a lot of time rolling back and restarting. For the same reason processing sorted array is faster than processing unsorted array.